# Check if a Python list item contains a string inside another string from another list

Tags: python

I have a list that contains countries like so:

```
country = ["england","france","germany"]
```

I would like to use this list and check if these values are within other string lists, such as:

```
urllist = ["http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/germany/oberliga/tus-mechtersheim-1914/hertha-wiesbach/2300594/head2head/","http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/india/u18-league/delhi-united-sc-u18/sudeva-u18/2397728/head2head/","http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/england/championship/bristol-city-fc/fulham-football-club/2247116/head2head/"]
```

The second value in `urllist` would be removed because it contains the value India and it's not in the country list, giving an end result of:

```
urllist = ["http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/germany/oberliga/tus-mechtersheim-1914/hertha-wiesbach/2300594/head2head/","http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/england/championship/bristol-city-fc/fulham-football-club/2247116/head2head/"]
```

Comment: So that's what you want to do - what exactly is the problem that you faced when trying to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the split function here, and then check if the country specified in url is allowed.

```
s  = 'http://a/date/france/other' 
country = s.split('/')[4] #Adapt this to your case
countries = ["england","france","germany"]

interesting_urls = [url for url in urllist if url.split('/')[4] in countries]
```

This will avoid (in)validating a country since an indian link may concern a topic with "england" in it.

Comment: This won't work if the country shows up in different parts of the url...

Comment: Sure this assumes the urls parted this way obey the same pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a list comprehension:

```
urllist_new = set([url for url in urllist for cnty in country if cnty in url])
```

which is equivalent to

```
urllist_new = []
for cnty in country:
    for url in urllist:
        if cnty in url:
            urllist_new.append(url)
urllist_new = set(urllist_new)
```

Comment: Devil is always in the details; your approach seems problematic if a URL matches 2+ countries (either because you have us and belarus or other overlapping countries) or if the url is like www.americanews.com/germany) and also doesn't handle case

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. That would only introduce duplicates into the list. I've added a fix for duplicates nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

Simple list comprehension will achieve this:

```
output = [i for k in country for i in urllist if k in i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the membership operator `in` to see if a string contains a substring. So, loop through `country`, and check if each element is in each url in `urllist`.

```
[url for c in country for url in urllist if c in url]
```

Answer (score 0):

here yet another variation of it, but this time using `any` to be more clear in the intention

```
>>> [url for url in urllist if any( c in url for c in country)]
['http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/germany/oberliga/tus-mechtersheim-1914/hertha-wiesbach/2300594/head2head/', 'http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/england/championship/bristol-city-fc/fulham-football-club/2247116/head2head/']
>>>
```

you can also build a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to use with the [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) if you want to specify the exact place in the url where you want to match the country

```
>>> import re
>>> exp=r"([^/]+/+){6}"+ "({})".format( "|".join(country) )
>>> exp
'([^/]+/+){6}(england|france|germany)'
>>> [ url for url in urllist if re.match(exp, url) ]
['http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/germany/oberliga/tus-mechtersheim-1914/hertha-wiesbach/2300594/head2head/', 'http://uk.soccerway.com/matches/2017/02/22/england/championship/bristol-city-fc/fulham-football-club/2247116/head2head/']
>>>
```

explanation of the expression:

- `[^/]+` means everything that is not a `/` one or more times
- `/+` is one or more `/`
- `([^/]+/+){6}` here I ask for exactly 6 groups of something like `*/*/*/*/*/*/` or in this case `*//*/*/*/*/*/`
- the rest should be self explanatory